# Why is a local ip address the largest referrer in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

after 2 weeks of running Google Analytics on a site I see most of the traffic is coming from this IP address: 192.168.110.1

I've added a filter to exclude it now, but why is it there and could it be a valid referrer?

[image]

Edit to explain my question more clearly:

1. I'm wondering why there is an ip address in my clients Google
   Analytics
2. How is it referring so much traffic?
3. Have I set something up wrong? if so how can I fix it?

Comment: It can be something on your local network such as a monitor tool or a script of some sort or it can be a forged request packet. Is this normal? NO. We do not know enough to comment on your scenario. You have not given us enough information. If you are hosting your site, you may want to check with your web host to see what private IP address block they are using and whether something has gone awry. Also, you can look at you log file and see what kinds of accesses these requests are and that may give you a clue. You can also block the IP address from your site. If you have log data, it may help.

Comment: Is that IP address one that you actually use on your local network?   Referrer headers are super easy to forge and there are browser tools that will let any user change their referrer to whatever they want.   Either some user did so, or you have something set up at that IP address that is causing referrals.

Comment: Hi, sorry my question is not clear enough, and many thanks for your answers.

Basically: 1. I'm wondering why there is an ip address in my clients Google Analytics 
2. How is it referring so much traffic?
3. Have I set something up wrong? if so how can I fix it?

I've excluded the ip address for now since I assume it is not a valid referrer. 

I'm not hosting this website myself, I don't know what a monitor tool or forged request packet is.

Comment: I checked the log file and found 55 references to that ip address, here is one: 203.206.166.123 - - [03/Dec/2014:04:45:45 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 42950 "http://192.168.110.1/loginpages/entry_portal.shtml?uname=4h3f@internet" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"

They all come from 203.206.166.123 - which is 'iiNet Limited'

I have a feeling my client is with a dodgy web host, what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

I think your client has an internal internet application running on their internal IP address of 192.168.110.1.   They use that application all the time and it has a link to their website.

If that is indeed the case, then Google Analytics would pick up on it.  (Why shouldn't it?)

Comment: Ok thanks Stephen, much appreciated. I'll ask them and report back...